# snowflake terraform create multiple table in one tf files

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create multiple table through tf in snowflake.
Below are the sample code.

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  database            = "AMAYA"
  schema              = "public"
  name                = "info"
  comment             = "A table."

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
    nullable = true

    default {
      sequence = snowflake_sequence.sequence.fully_qualified_name
    }
  }

  column {
    name     = "identity"
    type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
    nullable = true

    identity {
      start_num = 1
      step_num  = 3
    }
  }

resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  database            = "AMAYA"
  schema              = "public"
  name                = "arch_info"
  comment             = "A table."

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
    nullable = true

    default {
      sequence = snowflake_sequence.sequence.fully_qualified_name
    }
  }

  column {
    name     = "identity"
    type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
    nullable = true

    identity {
      start_num = 1
      step_num  = 3
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this script I get the error.

```
 A snowflake_procedure resource named "table" was already declared at str.tf:16,1-38. Resource names must be unique per type in each module.
```

The only solution I have tried and worked is to create different files for different table. however I have 100 of tables to create, and was wondering if there is simpler way of putting all in one file and run the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same name for a resource more than once, like `table`below:

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
```

Use different names:

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table_1" {
```

You should look into `for_each` and `dynamic` functions when needing to create lots of the same resource with different parameters:

[Terraform for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each)

[Terraform dynamic](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks)

With those, you can create complex maps that are defined on input and automatically create the required amount of resources, something like below (just an example with a couple of parameters):

```
locals {

  snowflake_tables = {
    
    info = {
      database = "AMAYA"
      ...

      columns = {
        
        identity = {
          type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
          nullable = true
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  
  for_each = local.snowflake_tables
  
  name     = each.key            # info
  database = each.value.database # AMAYA
  ...

  dynamic "column" {
    for_each = each.value.columns
    content {
      name     = setting.key
      type     = setting.value["type"]
      nullable = setting.value["nullable"]
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

With this technique, all you do is add more objects to the map for tables and columns. I've set the example in locals but you could have this as a variable input instead in a .tfvars file etc.

Comment: thanks a lot.. I wonder how silly I can be

Comment: In the code, the iterator variable is currently set to `setting`. It should be set to match the dynamic block label `column`. If we change the code to the following, it should work: `dynamic "column" {...  name = column.key... type = column.value["type"]... }`